# Prisma 2 optional query parameters?

Tags: prisma, prisma2

When working with Prisma, I've come accross the situation where a relational query parameter is optional and I find myself writing a query like this:

It's important to note that `bookId` can be of type `undefined` or `string`.

```
prisma.author.findMany({
   bookList: {
      some: {
          id: bookId
      }
   },           
});
```

The above query won't work correctly in case the value of `bookId` is `undefined`. I have yet to find an elegant solution for this. Some ideas?

Comment: What's the desired behavior if `bookId` is undefined? Should the query even run at all? You could provide a default using the nullish coalescing operator: `bookId ?? someDefault` or do a check for undefined before running the query.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. The desired behaviour is to behave as is no condition was given. In the case above this means returning all `authors`.

Answer (score 0):

```
      ...(bookId && some: {
          id: bookId
      })
```

try this.
and i guess you omit 'where' or 'select' or 'include'... or else.
( i can't rewrite query for you because i'm not aware of your db schema.)

check again prisma docs - findMany